# Lock-Free and Light-wieght mechanism to handle double data type concurrently

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-c++, concurrency, c++14

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
DWORD tID;
volatile double fps;

DWORD  WINAPI ThreadFunc(LPVOID param)
{

    while (1)
    {
         //Need lock-free solution here
        std::cout << GetCurrentThreadId() << " Thread:  " << fps << std::endl;      
        Sleep(1);
    }
    return 1;
}

void mainFunc(const double& pGps)
{
    //Perormance critical function - should be lightwieght as possible as it can
    fps = pGps; // need lock-free efficient solution
}

int main()
{
    double gps, pGps =0.0;
    auto fb1 = CreateThread(NULL, NULL, &ThreadFunc, &gps,0,&tID);
    while (1)
    {
        pGps = pGps + 1;
        mainFunc(pGps);
        Sleep(1);
    }
    system("Pause");
    return 0;
}
```

I am using Visual C++ compiler.
Here **fps** double variable is being shared among **main** thread and **fb1** thread, I need to establish concurrent write and read access in well synchronized mechanism. Here only two threads have to take account of. Main thread - ***Producer***(writer),fb1 thread will be the ***Consumer***(Reader).

### mainFunc should be lightweight

This is the problem ,**mainFunc** should be more light-weight and efficient as possible(less number of instructions).I tried different approaches using `std::atomic<double> fps`,Win32 Interlocked operations but I couldn't achieve performance expected.
Firstly I attempt to use **Slim R/W** lock but the solution should be lock-free mechanism, even though SRW locks not given performance the solution needed.

### If we use Lock-free data structure, would it be an efficient solution?

please check modified code below with introducing lock-free data structure

```
DWORD tID,tID1;
volatile double fps;

LK_Free_DataStructre datStruct;
DWORD  WINAPI ThreadFunc(LPVOID param)
{
        while (1)
        {
            size_t n = datStruct.size();
            for (auto i = 0; i < n; ++i)
            {
                std::cout << GetCurrentThreadId() << " Thread:  " << datStruct.get(i) << std::endl;
            }
            Sleep(1);
        }   
    return 1;
}

void mainFunc(double& pGps)
{
    datStruct.insert(pGps);
}

int main()
{
    double gps, pGps =0.0;
    auto fb1 = CreateThread(NULL, NULL, &ThreadFunc, &gps,0,&tID);
    while (1)
    {
        pGps = pGps + 1;
        mainFunc(pGps);
        Sleep(1);
    }

    system("Pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Assume that we have to define ***Lock-free*** and ***Light-weight*** data structure- that is **LK_Free_DataStructre**.
So what is the most suitable **Win32** or **C/C++** in built data-structure ,that could replace **LK_Free_DataStructre**?

Is `std::atomic<double>` recommended ?

Comment: "[...] not given performance the solution needed." what performance does the solution need? "please check modified code below"...well, did you compare it to the first code? What did you find?

Comment: I need to find which data structure should I use - like lock-free queue etc..

Comment: Such `LK_Free_DataStructre` will work only until it does not reallocate the memory internally. Since Producers are continuously producing so internal memory is bound to increase and reallocation would be required. In the absence of lock consumer might access the invalid memory at some point of time.

Comment: @sameerkn yeah your argument is correct. But assume you haven't that kind of situation.Without any data structure can we have any solution ?

Comment: when you tried [`std::atomic`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic), did you pick an appropriate [`std::memory_order`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order) for your needs as well ? Or did you just stick with the default ?

Comment: I stick with default.Have not configured the memory_order.
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic
Here only integral type has been defined. so std::atomic for floating-point has no meaning right?

Comment: If the situation is some thing like producers are not going to produce more than x elements then, simply using `std::vector` will work. Then, you need to `reserve` x elements in `vector` before starting producer and consumer.

Comment: @sameerkn I tried that .. using `std::vector` lock-free guaranteed ?

Comment: I think `std::vector` will be thread safe in your case, since producer and consumer won't be accessing element at same index at any point of time. Also `std::vector` do not use lock for element maintenance. Maintenance (insert/access) of elements is the responsibility of users using vector.

Comment: The templated version of `std::atomic` supports `double`. The default `std::memory_order` is the most strict. From what you explain, it sounds like `std::memory_order_relaxed` will work just fine for you (but obviously you'll want to validate that against your requirements). Give that a try, and see if that meets your performance requirements.

Comment: Interlocked operations are lock-free, and probably one of the fastest solutions. Which kind of performance do you need?

Comment: @SanderDeDycker I will try it again.

Comment: @Banex ,I faced a problem that how to integrate `double` with which win32 interlock operation?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest and fastest answer in this case is `std::atomic<double>` - it's basically designed for this. You just need to avoid the memory fence which std::memory_order_seq_cst imposes (the default memory order). Something like the following has no synchronisation at all, just atomicity (moves the memory of one double over another in one go), and so will almost be as fast as assigning a normal double variable, whilst still being safe.

```
#include <atomic>

std::atomic<double> fps;


void setFps(double val) {
  fps.store(val, std::memory_order_relaxed);
}

double getFps() {
  return fps.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
}
```

If you go with a lock free data structure (e.g. queue), then

- it will fill up and potentially block if the writer goes too fast
- it will be much slower

so I would just avoid that.

Microsoft's interlocked operations are basically the same as std::atomic, just non-standard and harder to use (IMO), so I would avoid that too.

Comment: I have done earlier the procedural you have mentioned.but question arisen, should we use `std::memory_order_relaxed`  on both **read/write**  instead of `std::memory_order_acquire`(read/load) and `std::memory_order_release`(write/store), theoretical reason?

Comment: acquire release will actually be the same on x86 due to the architecture, so it's a bit moot tbh. Strictly speaking though, what you use depends on what guarantees you want. Release means don't reorder writes after this one, and acquire means don't reorder reads before this one. E.g. if you have a spinlock protecting a resource, then you don't want the access to the resource to be reordered before/the .lock() call so you could use an atomic bool and release/acquire. In your case though, it seems you don't mind about protecting anything other than the one double, so relaxed should be fine.

Comment: Thanks for the info' ... great help really appreciated.

Comment: ,if you can,please provide an example hot to achieve above scenario using win32 interlocks operations? replacing `std::atomic<doouble>` by `volatile double`

Comment: I'm more of a linux guy, but I think you would have to use `InterlockedExchangeNoLock64(reinterpret_cast<long long*>(&fps), reinterpret_cast<long long>(val))` to write and `double val = reinterpret_cast<double>(InterlockedCompareExchangeNoLock64(reinterpret_cast<long long*>(&fps), -1,-1))` to read. Now you know why i think it's harder to use.

Comment: @ Joseph Ireland-I done same thing earlier with `InterlockedExchange64()`.Please click following link and tell me if I done any mistake,
http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d928a1bce49e0f36
Program run as expected.
**Please mention** - why did you use `InterlockedExchangeNoLock64` instead of `InterlockedExchange64` ?

Comment: oops, i meant `InterlockedExchangeNoFence()`. You can use it because you don't need a memory fence

Comment: yeah that's what I thought... I got confused earlier. I never heard such function :D,I used them,but earlier I thought that using `std::atomic` is kind of efficient,Do you prefer `Win32::Interlocked` over `std::atomic` as Linux guy? :D
Did you check the code I have written is it bug free?

Comment: and reading a double isn't necessarily atomic (e.g. in 32 bit applications), so you need to do an InterlockedCompareExchange with an unlikely value in order to read it, since windows doesn't give you an atomic load function.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135198/discussion-between-buddhika-gamage-and-joseph-ireland).

Comment: I definitely prefer std::atomic. The atcual compiled code will be similar anyway, but it's so much clearer without those `reinterpret_cast`s everywhere.

Comment: Thanx for the support and thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

> Here only two threads have to take account of. Main thread - Producer(writer),fb1 thread will be the Consumer(Reader).

Sounds like what you need is a single-producer/single-consumer queue.

You may like to have a look at [Boost Single-Producer/Single-Consumer Queue](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/doc/html/lockfree/examples.html#lockfree.examples.waitfree_single_producer_single_consumer_queue) usage example.

The good thing about single-producer/single-consumer queue is that it can be implemented in a wait-free fashion (in addition to being lock-free). That is, `push` and `pop` operations complete in a constant number of instructions, no busy waiting is involved.

Comment: I cannot use external libraries. yeah Single-Producer /Single-Consumer pattern I need. but the data structure or the mechanism should lightweight and lock-free.

Comment: @BuddhikaGamage _but the data structure or the mechanism should lightweight and lock-free._ - it is both lock-free and wait-free.

Comment: I will try to implement lk-free queue .

Comment: @BuddhikaGamage Note that wait-free is the strongest progress guarantee. Learn about lock-free vs wait-free https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-blocking_algorithm